# IEEE754 to floating point C#

Tags: c#, ieee-754

The below code is simple converting a 32bit-integer from the object being passed to the function, the 32-bit integer represents a floating number. I have checked with an online calculator that that i am getting the sign, exponent and mantessa the correct way but strangely i am getting the answer wrong.

Can anyone please check if i am mathematically (or maybe programmatically) doing it wrong somehow!?

Regards

```
public double FromFloatSafe(object f)
    {
        uint fb = Convert.ToUInt32(f);


        uint sign, exponent = 0, mantessa = 0;
        uint bias = 127;

        sign = (fb >> 31) & 1;
        exponent = (fb >> 23) & 0xFF;
        mantessa = (fb & 0x7FFFFF);
        double fSign = Math.Pow((-1), sign);
        double fMantessa = 1 + (1 / mantessa);
        double fExponent = Math.Pow(2, (exponent -bias));
        double ret = fSign * fMantessa * fExponent;
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes(fb)` and then `BitConverter.ToSingle()`?

Comment: Using `Math.Pow` for the fSign is a little overblown :-) `sign == 0 ? 1 : -1`. And it is mantissa, not mantessa.

Comment: Why are you passing the floating point number as an integer? What are you actually trying to do? C# can handle casts just fine, why are you using the wrong data types?

Comment: And you aren't handling denormal numbers... if exponent == 0...

Comment: `(double)fb` not working? Based on "32-bit integer represents a floating number" Please show example input/output.

Comment: It was a bit messed up as i really started on the wrong foot. but the correct answer is by @DmitryBychenko!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that:

```
  uint fb = Convert.ToUInt32(f);

  return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((int) fb), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This handles even denormal numbers:

```
public static float FromFloatSafe(object f)
{
    uint fb = Convert.ToUInt32(f);

    int sign = (int)((fb >> 31) & 1);
    int exponent = (int)((fb >> 23) & 0xFF);
    int mantissa = (int)(fb & 0x7FFFFF);

    float fMantissa;
    float fSign = sign == 0 ? 1.0f : -1.0f;

    if (exponent != 0)
    {
        exponent -= 127;
        fMantissa = 1.0f + (mantissa / (float)0x800000);
    }
    else
    {
        if (mantissa != 0)
        {
            // denormal
            exponent -= 126;
            fMantissa = 1.0f / (float)0x800000;
        }
        else
        {
            // +0 and -0 cases
            fMantissa = 0;
        }
    }

    float fExponent = (float)Math.Pow(2.0, exponent);
    float ret = fSign * fMantissa * fExponent;
    return ret;
}
```

**note that I do think there is something fishy here, but you asked for it, I wrote it**... I feel this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Ah... and note that while academically what I wrote is very interesting, I normally do it this way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct UInt32ToFloat
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint UInt32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float Single;
}
```

then

```
float f = new UInt32ToFloat { UInt32 = Convert.ToUInt32(f) }.Single;
```

Comment: Note: `struct` / `[FieldOffset]` is a very good approch (no calculations) - but only works for two types with same bit length (in this case 32 bit for uint/float)

Comment: @joe You can even use it to split high/low `Int32` of a `Int64` if you want... (or the 4x`Int16` of a `Int64`)

Comment: That's true, but I meant that converting a `Int16` to `double` will not work this way because of the sign.

Comment: @joe It wouldn't have any sense... This `struct` is useful to make binary conversions, not casts that change the format. You don't use it to cast between `int` and `short`... or a `float` to a `double`.