# How to convert a modbus 32-bit word to a C# float?

Tags: c#, floating, modbus

how to convert modbus 32 bit word  into a float point  in c#?

here is the code I have :

```
float Modbus_Floating(byte[] temp)
    {
        byte[] temp2 = new byte[4];
        temp2[0] = temp[3];
        temp2[1] = temp[2];
        temp2[2] = temp[1];
        temp2[3] = temp[0];

        float f = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(temp, 0);

        return f;
    }
```

it is not working,
I am getting a big negative number
I should get 36.7

```
    [0] 102 byte
    [1] 102 byte
    [2] 66  byte
    [3] 22  byte
```

but I am not getting that ..
why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Couples of things you need to check:**

- does your device match C# `float`'s norm IEEE-754 ?
- which endianness your device uses ?

  you can see below that endianness can be per `WORD`, opposed to `DWORD`

  http://store.chipkin.com/articles/modbus-floating-point-encoding

When you're sure about all these and `BitConverter` failed, you can always parse manually, [it's fairly easy as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002725/361899), providing you have the specifications.

Comment: @Brandon [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)